# Openssl BIO_read does not return

Tags: c, openssl, timeout, client

I have a problem with BIO_read I do not get rid of. I want to print the lines to the screen that came from the server. With the help of the gdb I could find out where the problem is but I don't what to do now. The problem is that the function is called correctly but then when BIO_read is executed it feels like an endless loop as it does not return or end.
My code looks like this:

```
//This function should print one line to screen
int WebPrintLine(BIO *bio) {
unsigned char *x;
unsigned int i;
unsigned char buffer[4096];
unsigned int sizeofbuffer = sizeof(buffer);

//Print each char until newline char or terminator char appear and next loop turn if it would affect memory not owned by the arry buffer
do {
    WebRead(bio, buffer, sizeofbuffer);

    for( i = 0; (buffer[i] != '\n') && (buffer[i] != '\0') && (i < sizeofbuffer); i++ )
        putchar(buffer[i]);

}while( (buffer[i] != '\n') && (buffer[i] != '\0') && (x != 0) );

putchar('\n');

return 0;
}


/*This function should receive and returns a char to the buffer
BIO_gets could also be used to get just one line but it does not work always so I have  not put it in
Return 0 on error*/
unsigned char *WebRead(BIO *bio, unsigned char buffer[], int sizeofbuffer) {
int bytes_read; //Temporarily store how many bytes were read: for error checking

bytes_read = BIO_read(bio, buffer, sizeofbuffer);
if( bytes_read == 0 ) {
    //No more data available on an non-blocking connection
    return 0;
}
else if( bytes_read < 0 ) {
    //Error occured, retry and if this fails return  0
    if( ! BIO_should_retry(bio) )
        return 0;
}
return buffer;
}
```

I am looking forward to hear from you.

The function WebPrintLine is called two more times before and works correctly. But in gdb the program stucks when BIO_read is called.

Does anyone has some experiences with that, I couldn't find anything relevant and on their site: [openssl](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BIO_read.html#) no such error is mentioned or I have notm found it yet.

Comment: Because the `BIO` stream is blocking? That means if there is no data to be read, the function will block (wait) for data to be available. Go to your favorite search engine and look for more information there.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg But on the openssl it says: "All these functions return either the amount of data successfully read or written (if the return value is positive) or that no data was successfully read or written if the result is 0 or -1. If the return value is -2 then the operation is not implemented in the specific BIO type. " For me it sounds like if there is no data it will return 0 or -1

Comment: And on the IBM site it says: "BIO_read will attempt to read a certain number of bytes from the server. It returns the number of bytes read, or 0 or -1. On a blocking connection, a return of 0 means that the connection was closed, while -1 indicates that an error occurred. On a non-blocking connection, a return of 0 means no data was available, and -1 indicates an error. To determine if the error is recoverable, call BIO_should_retry. " So if it would be blocking I would get a return, wouldn't I?

Comment: In the [**NOTES** section of the reference](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BIO_read.html#NOTES) it also says: "A 0 or -1 return is not necessarily an indication of an error. In particular when the ***source/sink is non-blocking*** or of a certain type it may merely be an indication that no data is currently available and that the application should retry the operation later." (emphasis mine). This seems to indicate that a BIO source can indeed be blocking. And sockets (the most common source I would think) are blocking by default.

Comment: And I would also say that your IBM quote fits my assumptions. In fact, the standard socket `read` (or recv`) function returns the same (`0` on connection closed by peer, `-1` on error) for blocking sockets. For non-blocking sockets, `read`/`recv` returns `-1` with a specific error saying that no data is available at the moment.

Comment: Yes, but for me it sounds like the function will return at least something and not just continue "forever" even if there may be a blocking socket.

Comment: But if the underlying source is a blocking socket, and `BIO_read` is a thin platform independent abstraction above the platforms `read` or `recv` functions, how would `BIO_read` be able to return if the underlying function doesn't return?

Comment: Ok, this could be possible. I will search for it, if you have any more suggestions or links or find out something else, please let me know. :-) Thanks for answering. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

I have found my error. I just write this if someone else has the same problems like me:

```
BIO_write(bio, buf_write, strlenbuf)
```

The problem was not BIO_write but the value of strlenbuf.
I had added two chars to the buf_write array but not updated the variable strlenbuf with stored the length of the string( strlenbuf = strlen(buf_write) ), so the string terminato ('\0') was not sended and so I had not finished my server request, and this caused this problem.